# Dioxin synthesis in a rocket stove riser?

Tags: combustion

I'm building a rocket stove for cooking with a wok at the top of the riser.  At the top of the riser I'm seeing temperatures of 500-700 deg C, and I believe at the bottom it's likely under 1000 deg C ( though others with optimised builds see temperatures closer to 1100 deg C ).  The firebox is comprised of firebricks with the roof and floor lined with ceramic fiber blanket, and the manifold, and riser are all lined with ceramic fibre blanket.

[image: enter link description here]

I gather that in the combustion of wood ( biofuels ) you can see de novo synthesis of dioxins and furans in two temperature windows 200-400 deg C, and 600-800 deg C with the latter being much less.

One sees more efficient combustion with the introduction of heated secondary air into the riser, but at these temperatures steel spalls and dies.  Steel pipes need to be replaced every year.

I have placed a copper pipe into the combustion chamber to provide secondary air and threaded it to the riser.  It didn't melt.

So, my question is, does copper help in catalysing the formation of dioxins ( catalytic stoves increase dioxin formation ) and does it matter at temperatures at the bottom of the riser since they should be destroyed?

Edit:

> Copper (Cu) is the most potent catalyst for dioxin formation, but Iron (Fe), Zinc (Zn), Potassium (K) and Sodium (Na) have also been found in multiple studies to be correlated with increased dioxin/furan formation. Some studies have also indicated that Manganese (Mn), Magnesium (Mg) and Nickel (Ni) may also serve as catalysts for dioxin formation. Studies have conflicted on whether Aluminum (Al) encourages or inhibits dioxin formation. One study below indicated that Silicon (Si) is negatively correlated with dioxin formation.

https://www.ejnet.org/dioxin/catalysts.html

Comment: The formation of dioxins depends a lot of what fuel you are using. Wet wood is the worst (sap contains a lot of chlorine) Dry wood is better. But if you are not using wood but purer fuels like charcoal or LPG there won't be much to worry about.

Comment: I use mainly HT pallet wood.